# Want to add to database, but not showing/Working

Tags: database

this code keeps saying that the "Record has been Added", yet it's no where to be seen on phpmyadmin...Any thoughts?

phpmyadmin: localhost>summative>Data

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
if(!$con)(die("could not connect " . mysql_error()));
mysql_select_db("summative") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Data(First Assister) VALUES('$_GET[assist1]')"); 
if("INSERT INTO Data(First Assister) VALUES('$_GET[assist1]'");
{
echo "Record Added";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have an error(s) in your query, but you never see them because the code *fails to correctly check for errors* - why are you "if"ing the query string? It's a string. Re-read the applicable section on error checking in `mysqli` or `PDO` - *don't* use `mysql_*`, it has been obsoleted - and then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: (Personally, I'd start with PDO and promoting errors to exceptions - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - as this eliminates many manual checks.)

Answer (score 0):

1.) mysql is now deprecated use mysqli... from https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended
> for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead,
> either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the
> MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

2.) Are you seriously setting $_GET data into your database?

3.) Are you seriously setting $_GET data into your database without escaping it?  ***ALWAYS*** escape user provided data when putting it into your databse unless you enjoy getting hacked by Chinese government sponsored hackers *(or Russian, or Netherlands, or Brazil... or lesser common countries, but those are the most common as far as I've been hack attempted)*

See the docs for `mysqli_real_escape_string`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

2.) Where are you getting that `INSERT` format from?   In MySQL the format is:

> INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

From: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Personally, I prefer the other INSERT format:

> INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY |
> DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
> [INTO] tbl_name
> [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
> SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...
> [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
> col_name=expr
> [, col_name=expr] ... ]

4.) What is your table name?  I see a DB name, and I THINK a column name, and then a value...

So I'd change your INSERT statement to this:

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['param']);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table_name` SET `column`="'.$value.'";';
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
```